# Best practice for creating a dynamic horizontal bar chart using Spring, Thymeleaf and Javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, chart.js, thymeleaf

Im relatively new to Spring and Thymeleaf but Ive managed to make a disc golf page showing the rounds played by a user with the courses  in an accordion and each course having each round. Image below, I can dynamically add all the holes, pars, scores etc and it (so far) works good, but my javascript is still very much beginner.

I'm trying to add a simple horizontal stacked bar for each round, but so far I get only a chart on the first round, and most importantly, get the dynamic score data into the chart? Right now its hard coded in the javascript using the 'const arr'.

So how can I have dynamic charts for each score card? Is it correct practice to pass the data using the th:attr?

Also I havent started trying to assign the color by score cause right now its hard coded. So like the score card, par is no color, 1 under par is blue, 1 over par is orange and a hole in one would be green.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link th:href="@{/css/fontawesome/css/all.css}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/discgolf/round.css}">

    <title>Rounds</title>


</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/navbars/libraryNavbar :: navbar"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="subContainer">
        <h1>Rounds</h1>
        <a class="col-sm-4" th:href="@{/discgolf}">Disc Golf Home</a>
        <div class="row" id="username">
            <b class="col-sm-8">Username:<span sec:authentication="principal.username"></span></b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a>Add Round</a>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/discgolf/newRound}" th:object="${course}"
          method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group blu-margin">
                <select th:name="course" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option th:value="0" th:text="${'Please Select'}"></option>
                    <option th:each="course : ${courses}"
                            th:text="${course.name}" >

                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <a>Rounds Played</a>
    </div>
    <div >
        <div th:each="roundCourse : ${rounds}" class="card">
            <button class="accordion">
                <span th:text="${roundCourse.key.name}"></span>

            </button>
            <div class="panel">
                <th:block th:each="round : ${roundCourse.value}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <label>Date: </label>
                            <label th:text="${#dates.format(round.roundDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <label>Score: </label>
                            <label th:text="${round.total - round.course.par}"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <canvas th:attr="data-counts=${round.scores}" id="myChart"></canvas>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div >
                        <table id="courseInfo" class="table table-bordered w-auto">
                            <th:block th:each="course : ${round.course}">
                                <tr>
                                    <th th:text="${'Hole'}"></th>
                                    <th th:each="hole : ${course.holes}" th:text="${hole.number}"></th>
                                    <th th:text="${'Total'}"></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td th:text="${'Par'}"></td>
                                    <td th:each="par : ${course.holes}" th:text="${par.par}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${course.par}"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td th:text="${'Score'}"></td>
                                    <th:block th:each="score : ${round.scores}">

                                        <td th:style="${score.score > score.holePar}
                                    ? 'background-color: red'
                                    : (${score.score < score.holePar } ? 'background-color: blue'
                                    : 'background-color: #eee' ) " th:text="${score.score}"></td>
                                    </th:block>
                                    <td th:text="${round.total}"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </th:block>
                        </table>
                        <br>
                        <a th:href="@{/discgolf/deleteRound/{id}(id=${round.roundId})}" title="Remove Course"
                           data-target="#deleteRoundModal" class="table-link danger" id="deleteRoundButton" >
                            <span id="deleteRound" class="fa-stack">
                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" title="Delete this round"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                </th:block>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var listRounds = [[${rounds}]];

</script>
<script>


</script>

<!--<div th:replace="/discgolf/fragments/deleteCourseModal :: deleteCourseModal"></div>-->


<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/discgolf/userRounds.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
const countsTest = document.getElementById('myChart').getAttribute('data-counts');
console.log("Counts Test: " + countsTest);

*** so the dynamic array would be here***
const arr = [3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4];
const counts = {};

for (const num of arr) {
  counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
}

console.log(counts);
console.log(counts[1], counts[2], counts[3], counts[4], counts[5]);


var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}


  new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'),{
      type: 'bar',
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
          x: {
            stacked: true,
            display: false
          },
          y: {
            stacked: true,
            display: false
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          }
        },
      },

      data: {
        labels: ["Score"],

        datasets: [{
          data: [counts[2]],
          backgroundColor: "#77ACD8"

        },{
          data: [counts[3]]
//          backgroundColor: "rgba(163,103,126,1)"
        },{
          data: [counts[4]],
          backgroundColor: "#FDC169"
        }]
      }
    }
  );
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/rounds/{id}")
    public String roundsHome(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id,
                             Model model) {
        List<Course> courses = courseService.getAllCourses();
        List<Round> rounds = userService.getUserById(id).getRounds();
        Map<Course, List<Round>> mapRoundsByCourse = rounds.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Round::getCourse));
        model.addAttribute("courses", courses);
        model.addAttribute("rounds", mapRoundsByCourse);
        return "/discgolf/round/rounds";
    }
```

Data

```
Course{id=2, name='Ilsede', holes=[Hole{holeId=46, number=1, par=3}, Hole{holeId=47, number=2, par=3}, Hole{holeId=48, number=3, par=3}, Hole{holeId=49, number=4, par=3}, Hole{holeId=50, number=5, par=3}, Hole{holeId=51, number=6, par=3}, Hole{holeId=52, number=7, par=3}, Hole{holeId=53, number=8, par=3}, Hole{holeId=54, number=9, par=3}, Hole{holeId=55, number=10, par=3}, Hole{holeId=56, number=11, par=3}, Hole{holeId=57, number=12, par=3}, Hole{holeId=58, number=13, par=4}, Hole{holeId=59, number=14, par=3}, Hole{holeId=60, number=15, par=3}, Hole{holeId=61, number=16, par=3}, Hole{holeId=62, number=17, par=3}, Hole{holeId=63, number=18, par=3}], par=55, record=7}
        =[Round{roundId=21, course=Course{id=2, name='Ilsede', holes=[Hole{holeId=46, number=1, par=3}, Hole{holeId=47, number=2, par=3}, Hole{holeId=48, number=3, par=3}, Hole{holeId=49, number=4, par=3}, Hole{holeId=50, number=5, par=3}, Hole{holeId=51, number=6, par=3}, Hole{holeId=52, number=7, par=3}, Hole{holeId=53, number=8, par=3}, Hole{holeId=54, number=9, par=3}, Hole{holeId=55, number=10, par=3}, Hole{holeId=56, number=11, par=3}, Hole{holeId=57, number=12, par=3}, Hole{holeId=58, number=13, par=4}, Hole{holeId=59, number=14, par=3}, Hole{holeId=60, number=15, par=3}, Hole{holeId=61, number=16, par=3}, Hole{holeId=62, number=17, par=3}, Hole{holeId=63, number=18, par=3}], par=55, record=7}, scores=[Score{scoreId=199, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=200, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=201, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=202, score=4, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=203, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=204, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=205, score=2, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=206, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=207, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=208, score=4, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=209, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=210, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=211, score=2, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=212, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=213, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=214, score=4, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=215, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=216, score=2, holePar=3}], roundDate=2023-03-01 00:00:00.0, total=54},
        Round{roundId=24, course=Course{id=2, name='Ilsede', holes=[Hole{holeId=46, number=1, par=3}, Hole{holeId=47, number=2, par=3}, Hole{holeId=48, number=3, par=3}, Hole{holeId=49, number=4, par=3}, Hole{holeId=50, number=5, par=3}, Hole{holeId=51, number=6, par=3}, Hole{holeId=52, number=7, par=3}, Hole{holeId=53, number=8, par=3}, Hole{holeId=54, number=9, par=3}, Hole{holeId=55, number=10, par=3}, Hole{holeId=56, number=11, par=3}, Hole{holeId=57, number=12, par=3}, Hole{holeId=58, number=13, par=4}, Hole{holeId=59, number=14, par=3}, Hole{holeId=60, number=15, par=3}, Hole{holeId=61, number=16, par=3}, Hole{holeId=62, number=17, par=3}, Hole{holeId=63, number=18, par=3}], par=55, record=7}, scores=[Score{scoreId=244, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=245, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=246, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=247, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=248, score=4, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=249, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=250, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=251, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=252, score=2, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=253, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=254, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=255, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=256, score=2, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=257, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=258, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=259, score=4, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=260, score=3, holePar=3}, Score{scoreId=261, score=3, holePar=3}], roundDate=2023-03-09 00:00:00.0, total=54}]
```

Image of roundId = 21 (I know colors dont match yet)
[image]

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
So I managed to get the bar chart working now, using a service call within Thymeleaf. I wont put the whole code up again but this is the thymeleaf and chart:

```
<div class="col-6">
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <canvas th:attr="data-counts=${roundService.getListOfScoresByRoundId(round.roundId)}" id="myChart"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

The sql call

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s.score from score s WHERE s.round_id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Integer> findAllScoresByRoundId(@Param("id") Long id);
```

The service method

```
@Override
    public List<Integer> getListOfScoresByRoundId(Long id) {
        return scoreRepository.findAllScoresByRoundId(id);
    }
```

and the updated chartjs

```
const countsTest = document.getElementById('myChart').getAttribute('data-counts');
const counts = {};

for (const num of countsTest) {
  counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}


  new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'),{
      type: 'bar',
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
          x: {
            stacked: true,
            display: false
          },
          y: {
            stacked: true,
            display: false
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          }
        },
      },

      data: {
        labels: ["Score"],

        datasets: [{
          data: [counts[2]],
          backgroundColor: "#77ACD8"

        },{
          data: [counts[3]]
        },{
          data: [counts[4]],
          backgroundColor: "#FDD79C"
        },{
           data: [counts[5]],
           backgroundColor: "#FDC26A"
         },{
             data: [counts[6], counts[7], counts[8], counts[9], counts[10]],
             backgroundColor: "#FCAE37"
           }]
      }
    }
  );
```

Again my javascript isnt great but Im only getting the bar chart in the first round displayed (image below), I guess its not looping each. Right now each accordion with class="panel" is displayed so why doesn't the bar show in each?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamic charts"? When should the chart update? Will the user press on a button or how should it work?

Comment: I've added an update, I guess when I say dynamic charts, it means there should be as many charts as there is rounds. But I'm only getting a chart for the first round displayed.

Comment: The call that you do in `th:attr` is only done once, when Thymeleaf renders the HTML and sends it to your browser. If you want things to happen when the HTML is already in the browser, you will need to use `fetch` in JavaScript, or something like htmx.org (See https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/10/04/todomvc-with-thymeleaf-and-htmx/ for a blog post that combines Thymeleaf and htmx or watch a video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POK4Zp1oRN8)

Comment: Thank you, but do you mine elaborating with maybe an example? Possibly an example using my code?